# Why is RSpec not passing my headers to Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to test my Rails application using RSpec, but my tests are failing because RSpec seems to not be passing the headers I give it to Rails.

I have a `UsersController` that includes `ApplicationHelper`, and in ApplicationHelper I have a method that accesses the `headers` hash. Indexing it by my `SESSION_KEY` header returns `nil`. If I `puts headers` inside that method, the hash does not contain the header I have supplied, only the following: `{"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff"}`.

Here is the relevant part of my RSpec spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Api::V1::UsersController, type: :request do
  let(:user) { User.create(name: 'TestUser', email: 'someone@example.com', password: 'password123', password_confirmation: 'password123') }
  let(:id) { user.id }
  let(:sess) { user.sessions.create }

  before { get "/api/v1/users/#{id}" }

  # Snipped other tests

  context 'with authentication' do
    context 'with a valid id' do
      it 'returns full user information' do
        get "/api/v1/users/#{id}", nil, {'HTTP_SESSION_KEY': sess.key}
        response_user = response_json[:user]
        expect(response.status).to eq 200
        expect(response_user).to_not be_nil
        expect(response_user[:name]).to eq user[:name]
        expect(response_user[:email]).to eq user[:email]
      end
    end
  end

  def response_json
    JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true)
  end
end
```

I have also tried passing the `SESSION_KEY` header without HTTP_ before it, and that did not work. I have also tried moving it up to the top `get` in the `before` block to see if it was a context issue, and that did not work either.

Comment: Note that `{'HTTP_SESSION_KEY': sess.key}` should be with hashrocket: `{'HTTP_SESSION_KEY' => sess.key}`

Comment: @nsave For a second I thought that might've been the source of my problems, but it isn't... Any idea what might be?

Comment: it seems you're doing 2 `get` requests every time, first one in `before` block and second one in `it` block. Is it intentional?

Comment: @AlexeyShein No, it is not intentional, but it shouldn't matter. And I thought if I added a second GET request, it would ignore the one in before.

Answer (score 1):

Docs say the above should work, but if for some reason rspec is interpreting your test as a `:controller` test and not a `:request` test then you need to do this (just before your `get` call):

```
request.env["HTTP_SESSION_KEY"] = sess.key
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything, the headers hash stays the same according to the controller.